# Wrapping C++ into Objective-C for native iOS development

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, swig

I am trying to wrap already written C++ codes into Objective-C using "swig".

This is the solution approach that i am trying to follow : [link](https://github.com/maxep/swig-objc)

Basically i am using modified version of the swig in order to wrap into Objective-C. However during the installation steps i get the error message bellow;

```
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-ansi'
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_swig_objectivec", referenced from:
modules in swigmain.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [eswig] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make: *** [source] Error 2
```

What i notice after investigating the error message, 'Modules/obj.o' file has not been created while compiling swig.
Then i modified my "Makefile.in" added necessary lines for obj.cxx, now swig creates 'Modules/obj.o' files however this time i get the error message bellow;

```
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `Modules/obj.cxx', needed by
`Modules/obj.o'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make: *** [source] Error 2
```

Any help will be appreciated.

**EDIT**

In order to get the error messages listed above i made some file changes in the given project link. So maybe the first steps that i followed were wrong, so this is the error message that i get at very beginning (btw i kept getting the given error message even if i configured both 'automake' and 'autoconf');

```
configure.ac:15: error: possibly undefined macro: AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE 
If this token and others are legitimate, please use m4_pattern_allow.
See the Autoconf documentation.
configure.ac:33: error: possibly undefined macro: AM_PROG_CC_C_O
configure.ac:35: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_COMPILE_WARNINGS
configure.ac:48: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_DEFINE
configure.ac:86: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_MSG_FAILURE
configure.ac:3041: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_DEFINE_DIR
```

Comment: The error shows you are missing some library

Comment: `SWIG` has a thread about [Objective-C Support](https://github.com/swig/swig/issues/827), but seems is work in progress yet (as they need someone to develop it). The only other **`SWIF` alternative** I know would be [Djinni C++](https://github.com/LedgerHQ/djinni), but that was not updated since 2019.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can't comment yet so I'll put it here. By wrap, do you mean that you want to compile and use c++ frameworks/code in your objective-c app? If so, I have found the easiest and most reliable way is to just app the files/frameworks and set the project compiler to see the language as objective-c++. Does this make sense? If I miss understood the question, please let me know :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, even if it does make sense, it doesn't work for my problem. I am familiar with the development process with obj-c++ and c++ however what i need to do is develop a Swift application. It is not possible to use obj-c++ codes in Swift yet i can use obj-c codes with bridge. That's why i am trying to modify swig and generate obj-c codes.

Comment: Ah you are making a swift application, then yes of course this option wont work. Sorry that I couldn't help out